# How to tokenize contractions in Python?

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I have sentences that I want to tokenize, including the punctuations. But I need to handle contractions so that words which are something+not like "can't" is tokenized into "ca" and "n't" where the split is one character before the apostrophe, and the rest of the contraction words split at the apostrophe like "you've" and "It's" turn into "you" "'ve" and "It" and "'s". This is where I'm stuck. Basically roughly equivalent to how to NKTL's TreebankWord Tokenizer behaves:
[NLTK Word Tokenization Demo](http://text-processing.com/demo/tokenize/)

I've been using one of the solution proposed on here which doesn't handle contractions the way I want it to:

```
re.findall("'\w+|[\w]+|[^\s\w]", "Hello, I'm a string! Please don't kill me? It's his car.")
```

and I get this result:

> ['Hello', ',', 'I', "'m", 'a', 'string', '!', 'Please', 'don', "'t", 'kill', 'me', '?', 'It', "'s", 'his', 'car', '.']

Which handles the apostrophes correctly except in the don't case where it should be "do" and "n't". Anyone know how to fix that?

I can only use the standard library, so the NLTK is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex:**

```
\w+(?=n't)|n't|\w+(?=')|'\w+|\w+
```

**Usage**

```
match_list = re.findall(r"\w+(?=n't)|n't|\w+(?=')|'\w+|\w+","you've it's couldn't don't", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

**Matches:**

```
['you', "'ve", "it", "'s", 'could', "n't", "do", "n't"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
r"[n]'[\w]+|[\w]+(?!')(?:[A-Za-mo-z](?='))?|(?<=\s)[\w](?=')|[^\s\w']"
```

This matches character followed by `'` followed by more characters and will match *first* even if it is able to match the other patterns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but the result is not quite what I wanted. The string "Hello, I'm a string! Please don't kill me? It's his car." produces this result:

['Hello', ',', "I'm", 'a', 'string', '!', 'Please', 'don', "'", 't', 'kill', 'me', '?', 'It', "'", 's', 'his', 'car', '.']

but I want:

['Hello', ',', 'I', "'m", 'a', 'string', '!', 'Please', 'do', "n't", 'kill', 'me', '?', 'It, "'s", 'his', 'car', '.']

Comment: I've modified my regex above to get something close to what I want, but the n't is still not being tokenized correctly.

Comment: It almost works but for the [\w]'[\w]+ case I'm only really looking for n't (can't, didn't, couldn't, etc) and nothing else (So "It's" should not be tokenized into "I" and "t's"). All other contractions should be tokenized at the apostrophe ("It's" tokenized as "It" and "'s").

Comment: Updated again.  You want some very specific rules, and the regex is complicated, so you may want to find an alternative to tokenizing with regex

Answer (score 0):

Catch `n't` and `\w+(?=n't)` before `\w+`

```
r"'\w+|n't|\w+(?=n't)|\w+|[^\s\w]"
```